# How can I write this syntax if there is space in column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I write this syntax if there was space in the column name "image_path"? Instead of "image_path", I have "image path". I changed the column name so it works. However, I was wondering if there is any way I can write this syntax without changing column name from "image path" to "image_path".

```
(df.groupby('content_type').image_path.nunique())
```

Thank you, 
Shone

EDIT:  Just in case the answer below is deleted:

```
df.groupby('content_type')['image path'].nunique()
```

Comment: @tarashypka  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `[...]` indexer with a string:

```
df.groupby('content_type')['image path'].nunique()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't accept within certain period and I had to leave my computer.